# Clustering points in 3D plane

Tags: python, cluster-analysis, k-means

Suppose we have 1000 random data points in a cube (as shown in the following image). The distribution of points in X and Y directions are uniform but not in Z direction. As we get deeper, the data points are denser. Is there any straightforward way in python to cluster these data points such that:

- each cluster has equal size
- each cluster consists of local points, i.e., each cluster consists of points being close to each other.

I have already tried K-means clustering from Scipy package but it did not give me a good result and the points of each cluster were very widespread rather than being concentrated.

[image]

Comment: Note: K-means is initialized randomly, have you tried running it several times to see if you just didn't have bad luck the first time? But in general, if your data is not clustered in the first place no algo is going to find good clusters that do not exist. This seems more like a binning problem...

Comment: @JulienBernu Yes I have tried it several times with different initialization and different umber of iterations for convergence.

Comment: The constraint that the clusters must have equal size is very strong. Take a look at this post: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/40777/spatial-clustering-with-the-constraint-that-all-clusters-have-equal-count

Comment: You no longer have a typical clustering problem once you have that constraint

Comment: There are no clusters here. Two attributes are uniform (= should be discarded). Can you show an example of what you would expect?

Comment: @Anony-Mousse According to the rest of comments, maybe a better explanation is that I want to divide this cube to sum mini-cube such that in each mini-cube there are equal number of data points.

Comment: You then should rephrase your question, and look at octrees.

Answer (score 0):

Try using Scikit-Learn's implementation. They initialize their clusters using a technique known as "K-Means++" which picks the first means probabilistically to get an optimal starting distribution. This creates a higher probability of a good result.

http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.KMeans.html